# Input control width restricted in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webforms project in asp.net.  I'm using bootstrap 3.  I have an input control in a form group (in a panel).  I cannot override the max width of my input control to make it fit into the col width I have set.
I've tried to amend/remove the input {max-width} attribute in Site.css but this doesn't make any difference.  Any ideas?

```
                 <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <label for="txtName" class="col-md-3 control-label">*Material Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <input runat="server" id="txtName" type="text" class="form-control" title="" required  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
```

Site.css extract that I changed from max-width: 287px :

```
/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the developer to tools on any of the browser to check the element of `input` because you're using `runat="server"` for the `input` the `id` will render differently in the browser hence your styling is not applying. I've checked on my local dev with a demo page and the `input` id is being rendered as `MainContent_txtName` instead of `txtName`. Of course yours will/might be different. Once you have the correct `id` all you need to do is

```
#MainContent_txtName
{
  max-width: 100px !important;
}
```

I hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks Izzy.  I changed the css to include the MainContent_txtname attribute (it was rendered this way for me too), however this didn't work.  It's like there is another place that the control is inheriting its width from in ASP.

Comment: Looking at the rules through the browser, it appears that Site.css is still setting the max width attribute to 280px.  However, I have definitely changed this in my project.  Hmmm.

Comment: Figured it out - Site.css was cached in my browser.  Thanks for your help Izzy.